# Flutter: file_picker_error, Temporary file could not be created

Tags: ios, flutter, macos

I am getting this error, in flutter code, on Mac M1:

[MethodChannelFilePicker] Platform exception: PlatformException(file_picker_error, Temporary file could not be created, Error Domain=NSItemProviderErrorDomain Code=-1000 "Cannot load representation of type public.item" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot load representation of type public.item}, null)
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(file_picker_error, Temporary file could not be created, Error Domain=NSItemProviderErrorDomain Code=-1000 "Cannot load representation of type public.item" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot load representation of type public.item}, null)

```
final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
    allowMultiple: false,
    type: FileType.image,
);
```

I also inserted this code in info.plist:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string>Explain why your app uses music</string>
<key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key>
<true/>
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are probably trying with the photo of the pink flowers on the simulator — that's a known iOS simulator issue since iOS 14. Please ignore it or test it on a real device.

Comment: I got the error on all the photo in simulator though. Im using mac mini m1 and ios 15 simulator. Most of people with this error usually use the same device and simulator like me I think.

Answer (score 3):

this error is due to the fact that you probably select the flower images in the emulator I found the solution to this problem at this link

https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/issues/997#issuecomment-1070981727

Comment: It is recommended to actually post the answer, instead of an URL. This is because it is nog guaranteed to exist forever and its content may change. Editing your answer will help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment line 2 of Podfile and set the version to

```
platform :ios, '13.0'
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your info.plist should contain this permissions

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Requires Camera Usage</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Requires Photo Library Usage</string>
```

Comment: Apparently the problem is a iOs simulator bug. I have tried on the device and it works fine.

Comment: thanks for the information, but it didn't solve the problem.thanks for the information, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @MaurizioMancini were able to solve this ?

Comment: no, apparently it's an ios simulator bug.